# Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire2

I am getting a bunch of errors on my build pipeline (wercker) but it works very well on my local env when I do a firebase deploy

Not sure if this is related to angualarfire2 version mismatch?

```
   ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts (14,62): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts (12,28): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts (13,35): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts (14,35): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts (15,44): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts (12,32): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts (15,48): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts (16,92): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts (11,31): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts (12,37): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
    ERROR in /pipeline/source/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts (13,24): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i downgraded from firebase 4.5.0 to 4.3.0 .
so resolved

Answer (score 2):

firebase.Promise was removed in version 4.5.0 of the firebase SDK. Now you just use a regular Promise. The following modification fixes your sample.

```
      signIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
        return this.auAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

npm uninstall firebase

npm install --save firebase@^3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Had to update to the lastest version of angularfire2 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1199)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to

"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
"firebase": "^3.9.0"

in package.json is worked for me.